# How would I put this code together?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a Javascript program working in three different places: [here,](http://jsfiddle.net/x5xH5/12/) 
[here,](http://jsfiddle.net/x5xH5/11/) and [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/x5xH5/10/)
But I don't know how would I put them in one file. This is where I am at right now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<style>
body {
background-color:#E4E0FF;
}
#canvas {
border:10px solid red;
background-color:white;
}
#canvas2 {
border:10px solid red;
background-color:white;
}
#canvas3 {
border:10px solid red;
background-color:white;
}
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">
</canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="400" height="300">
</canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3" width="400" height="300">
</canvas>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var $canvas = $("#canvas");
var canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX = $canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY = $canvas.scrollTop();

var toggle=0;
var x=150;
var y=100;
var w=100;
var h=100;
var r=60;
var wasInside=false;

ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

function changeColor() {
if (toggle == 0) {
ctx.fillStyle = "#04B45F";
toggle = 1;
} else if (toggle ==1){
ctx.fillStyle = "#04B45F";
toggle = 2;
}else if (toggle == 2){
ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
toggle = 3;
}else if (toggle == 3){
ctx.fillStyle == "#190707";
toggle = 4;
}else if (toggle == 4){
ctx.fillStyle = "#210B61";
toggle = 5;
}else if (toggle == 5){
ctx.fillStyle = "#FA58AC";
toggle = 6;
}else if (toggle ==6){
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
toggle = 7;
}else{
ctx.fillStyle = "#F5A9D0";
toggle = 0;
}

ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}

 function changeRadius() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0, 400, 300);
    r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 80) + 20);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(200, 150, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  function changeWidth() {
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
ctx.fillRect(0,0, 400, 300);    
width = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
ctx.lineWidth=width;
ctx.stroke();

}

 function handleMouseMove(e) {
 var mx = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
 var my = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

 var isInsideNow = (mx > x && mx < x + w && my > y && my <= y + h);

if (isInsideNow && !wasInside) {
changeColor();
wasInside = true;
} else if (!isInsideNow && wasInside) {
wasInside = false;
}

}

$("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvas2").mousemove(function (e) {
handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvas3").mousemove(function (e) {
handleMouseMove(e);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, how would I tell the program to do circle thing in 2nd canvas and line in 3rd canvas???
I haven't called the changeWidth and changeRadius functions yet, because it'll just do it in the first canvas making a mess.
I just need something in this part of the code to call different functions in different canvas's

```
 if (isInsideNow && !wasInside) {
     changeColor();
     wasInside = true;
 } else if (!isInsideNow && wasInside) {
     wasInside = false;
 }
```

Comment: Are you wanting 3 canvases/1 javascript controlling all 3 canvases file or are you wanting 1 canvas that does all the rect and circle and line?

Comment: Yes, I want 3 canvas's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a canvas expert, but just for giving you an idea, check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/x5xH5/16/)

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
```

inspect these 2 lines, the context `ctx` wil draw in the canvas with `id=canvas`. you can create other contex variables to draw in the other canvas or reuse the same.

*updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/x5xH5/17/)*

*Update for the update: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/x5xH5/28/)*

Comment: But it's only reacting to mouse movement in the first canvas! And i'm trying to make them independent of each other.

Comment: it's still not independent, what i want is, if i move the mouse over the first canvas than the change should always be in the first canvas, and same for the other two, they should be independent of each other.

Comment: @user3421518 you can simply handle them in mousemove event handler.. that's the easy part.. check this http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/x5xH5/17/would be nice of you to accept answer if it solved it the issue

Comment: It works (well almost) if i dont change anything at all and try to run it from a browser it still doesn't work and even on jsfiddle the first two canvas works and second one works when I scroll down a bit but the  last one doesn't work at all. Any reason why is this hpning?

Comment: WADR, this is not a correct answer :-[  The OP wanted effects to take place on all 3 canvases.  And since there are 3 canvases which require scrolling to come into view, you must also adjust for the scroll position.

Comment: @markE the OP wanted to put his code together and Make it work.  SO is a not the place where people write exact code for others. Hope you already know that.

Comment: @TilwinJoy: Understood...you're answer doesn't work.

Comment: @Mark You might want to read the title and question again. He wanted to put his code together and draw in different canvas on mouse move. which is done. Previosly his page had no scroll, now it has, it's his job to account for the scroll or resize the canvas, if he is having trouble with that he may post another question regarding so. it's not my job to follow up all the day fixing issues untill his application/website completes.SO is a Q & A site.

Comment: Instead of going back and forth on eacthother, you guys probably should've tried to solve the issue.

Comment: @user3421518 Fair enough :) I've added an answer that addresses the issues.

Comment: @TilwinJoy feel so old when I argue, but...I stand by what I said.  At the time of my comments (16 hours ago), your code simply did not work.  The circle and rectangle did not change on mouseenter.

Comment: @markE you can see this jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/x5xH5/17/ in a comment i posted 17 hours ago, which does work apart from when the window is not fully scrolled making the canvas in center. that was the solution for OP's question. the problem with scroll is the problem with the calculations in his code, which is not related to what he wants in this question.

Comment: @TilwinJoy:  http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/x5xH5/17/ is not working for me.  When I mouse near the circle, it should change radius (it doesn't). When I mouse near the rect, it should change color (it doesn't). When I mouse near the line, it should change width (it does!).

Comment: Well it does. if the canvas is properly on the center of the screen. that is clearly a problem with the rest of his code.  i gave him a quick solution and pointed him @ the right direction, while it was 2am here. after a day or so when you have loads of free time anyone can sit and correct all the code.
i'm reminding you again that the OP's actual problem was not being able to draw at different canvas in same page at same time which is related to the context, not related to a circle or rect you are talking about.

Comment: Argh!  Your version#17 Fiddle correctly changes the line on top, but it **does not change the circle or the rectangle, even when displayed full-screen to avoid the scrolling issue**.  You know version#17 is not working because by version#28 you have correctly solved the mouseenter issue.  BTW, the scrolling issue doesn't appear to be fixed even in your version#28 Fiddle. BTW, scrolling is a simple fix that's only 23 characters long: + $(window).scrollTop().  Anyway, this argument is taking too much energy for me...so I'm done.  My apologies for arguing--I get that way sometimes!  :)

Comment: well, this is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/uzz73/1/ that you came up with 10 hours afterwards, change the window size to align the canvas horizontally or vertically, and find your solution not working when the initial alignment is changed. i'd like to again and again remind you that this is was not the OP's problem, he never even had a scroll in his pages. this question is not about scrolling or canvas position.
p.s there is no scrolling issue in #28, it's working fine whether canvas are aligned vertically or horizontally. I'm not coming back to this argument.